# Weird black view showing app in the fragment next to Skobbler because of the Skobbler map

Tags: android, android-fragments, skmaps

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 children in my `MainActivity`.

One child is a fragment called `WalkMapFragment` that holds the `SKMapFragment` within,

(since I wasn't able to use the Skobbler maps by defining the `SKMapViewHolder` item on the xml) 
[image: Tab1-ViewPager Child 1]

and the other is an `About` fragment. But when I tap on the About tab item, I get this:
[image: Tab2]

Theres a black View on top of my fragment that shouldn't be there.

Now notice something weird, if I tap on an annotation and open a callout view in the map fragment like so:

check what happens:

[image: Tab1Again][image: Tab2Again]

Notice that the black view from the right tab moves exactly to `SKCalloutView`'s position

(Optional - Additional info:)

p.s 1: If I open a callout, then zoom in and out by hand, the black view disappears from my `About` Fragment.

p.s 2: By testing I found out that by removing the map, this weird black view also gets removed from the `About` fragment.

p.s 3: Also if I flip the tabs and put the `About` fragment on the left, I don't get this behaviour. It only happens when I have a fragment on the right side of the `Skobbler` map.

What is this issue about? How can I remove this black view that overlays my fragment?

Comment: Try Making map layout visibility invisible or gone when you go to 'about' tab.

Comment: Setting the `WalkMapFragment` visibility to `GONE` did do the trick as you suggested. Setting it to `INVISIBLE` on the other hand didn't do anything.

I'm still curious as to what I'm doing wrong though..!

Comment: In the "About" tab do you have another map?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making map layout visibility invisible or gone when you go to the 'about' tab.